# Can I altranate bicep workout as heavy day and light day?

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, muscle-gain, muscle-recovery

I workout 6 days a week

- Day 1 Chest/ tricep
- Day 2 Back/ **bicep**
- Day 3 Legs/ core/ shoulders
- Day 4 **Rest**
- Day 5 Chest/ tricep
- Day 6 Back/ **bicep**
- Day 7 Legs/ core/ shoulders

On back bicep days, I am planning to 1st day (day 2) as bicep heavy and 2nd day (day 6) as bicep lightweight, after heavy biceps day I have 3 days rest before the next light bicep day

**Day 2 plan heavyweight**  6-8 reps, 2min rest

1. barbel curl
2. EZ curl
3. Dumble curl
4. Dumble hammer

**Day 6 plan lightweight** 12-15 reps, 1min rest

1. Incline dumbbell curl
2. Behind body cable curl
3. Dumble concentration curl
4. Dumble Spider curl

With this split, I hope to train strength on Day-2, Then bicep peak and width on Day-6

Is this a good split, it's my 3rd-year weight training

Comment: We need to know a bit more about what you are trying to do. What are your goals? As written, this question is rather trivial, "can you?", of course you can.

Comment: @Thomas Markov, i am trying to increase bicep strength and bicep size

Comment: @kobi89 both your day 2 and day 6 plans will increase bicep strength and size. The variety is probably beneficial, but you're not definitely not just training strength on one day and size on the other.

Answer (score 4):

Choosing between alternating heavy/light is very low on the list of questions that actually matter when it comes to something as general as "increasing strength and size". So in short...

Yes, you can.